# How long does it take from uploading ftp for it to show http?

Tags: php, http, ftp

Quick question; I replaced a .css file which I was referencing in html/php that has an  absolute address of : http:/www.[my silly domain].com/css/div_image_container.css.

When I access it directly, it gives me an OLDER version of a file I have uploaded into the ftp structure.
However, in my main page, using a relative based directory, eg:

```
<?php
if (condition true){
    print("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\"
    href=\"/css/div_image_container.css\"
    MEDIA=screen />");
}
```

It 'magically' uses the correct, updated script. What is this? Is there somewhat of delay between when I upload through ftp and when my page gets served 'correctly'?

I am using fatcow, and they use sftp, which shouldn't matter.

I am just confused. When I access the file through ftp, it is the correct one.

Wait a minute, let me think. FZ has an url copy thing. When I copy a url, it gives something in the form of
ftp://[domain name]@ftp.[domain name].com/css/div_image_container.css

When I reference things in html without a http://, is it somehow always executing a ftp? But every user on the planet and beyond would need credentials, or at the very least read privileges.

Any way it's been 30+ minutes and the http:// address for that css file still contains the wrong code.

There is clearly some sort of separation between ftp http, obvious in name, but this is the first time that my assumption that an upload via ftp is reflected, in due time, almost equivalently in 'retrieval' through http has been shaken.

Comment: I'm gonna _assume_ you've tried clearing your browser cache.. are you sure you're uploading it to the right spot on the server, or even the right server?

Comment: Yes Ben, haha, but I will recheck just for you. I guess human error and assumption is much more probable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be immediate.

add a query string eg

http://example.com/?345678

and it will prevent caching,

double check you are uploading to the correct place,
failing that talk to your provider

Comment: Thanks. I... I thought I had tried to 'empty' Chrome's cache, but maybe I had forgotten, which is the likely case vs. a machine. If it comes down to it, and we know it won't, I'll talk to my provider, but thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

You are very likely running into a caching problem. It is typical for resources to be cached and served from cache for some period of time before being fetched again from the original source. This is done in order to reduce end-user latency (if it is cached locally, it is much faster than going through several hops, and if it is cached at one hop away, that is still faster than going out three hops to get it).

This is actually a good thing in terms of speeding up web applications, and if you never change a file, you can even set the cache expiration to never, so that it will always be served from cache. In order to force the resource to be fetched, you can set the caching policy to never cache the file (or to a very small amount); however, that will have a latency impact on your users. An alternative, which gives you the best of both worlds, is to never modify the resource at all, set the cache policy to cache indefinitely, add a unique signature onto the name of your resource that you use for versioning, upload your new CSS file with a different signature, and then modify your PHP file to point to the CSS file with the new signature. The change in the resource name will force the resource to be fetched (since the name differs from the one that was cached), but the "cache forever" policy will make subsequent loads fast.

Comment: Ahhhhh I get it. This + Surreal's response makes it seem like it is done in industry, plus the fact it makes sense, and therefore I will begin to do it. Thank you gentlemen.

Comment: Just tried it out, and the idea networked with my limited java experiences with subversion etc.; it works incredibly well. THANK YOU VERY MUCH GUYS! ~Newbie

Answer (score 1):

Agree with the caching issue.

A quick and dirty solution is to delete the calling php script (and sometimes related files), call the url from your browser (forcing a 404 error), then re-uploading the script file.  It should then be fresh.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also confident it's a caching issue.  A simple method to prevent caching is to add a unique parameter on your CSS file name every time.  You can make a basic and predictably unique parameter like this:

```
<?php
if (condition true){
    print("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\"
    href=\"/css/div_image_container.css?" . time() . "\"
    MEDIA=screen />");
}
```

This will append a Unix timestamp to the CSS filename as a parameter, giving a new parameter every second.  As long as you don't load the page more often than that, your browser won't hit the cache when it loads the stylesheet.

Comment: Hmm, I see what you did there, and I had never thought of it. Thanks SD, and everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old  thread, but I came across it when I was experiencing a similar problem and thought my info might help someone else:

From my fatcow support ticket:
"Thank you for contacting us.

It appears to be issue with the varnish cache since we use Varnish Caching technology on our server. The default Varnish Cache time limit is setup as 4 hours on our servers. Thus, your website may not display the changes immediately. For the better performance, I have disabled the cache at: https://www.fatcow.com/controlpanel/cachecontrol/ . "

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add that I just had the same experience and it was clearly due to the server's caching.

I edited one attribute on my stylesheet manually through FileZilla, then saved it. When I went to the actual live page, nothing changed. Even when when I refreshed the FTP connection and looked at the file, confirming the attribute was 100% there, the page was rendering the old file's output. It just *wasn't* being reflected on the live site.

Then: Three hours later, I came back to the site, and lo and behold, the page element I added the attribute to has changed.

I'm not a professional (yet), so I can't give much detail in my answer. However, my one source is the specialist who is training me/helping me set our website up. He noted earlier in the process that our hosting provider appears to have very aggressive caching. I can only assume that is the answer for the delay in updating my file.